# Investigate monotony, boundedness, and convergence of the sequence $\frac{2^n}{(n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I'm doing an exercise in the college, and I ran into a doubt: a friend says me that I've made a mistake, but I can't find it.

The exercise asks: "Investigate if the sequence $2^n\over{(n+1)!}$  is monotone, bounded in $\Bbb R$ and convergent".

i) MONOTONY:
$${{2^{(n+1)}\over{(n+2)!}}\over{2^n\over{(n+1)!}}}={{2^{(n+1)}(n+1)!}\over{2^n(n+2)!}}={{2.2^n(n+1)!}\over{2^n(n+2)!}}={{2(n+1)!}\over{(n+2)!}}={{(2n+2)(n)!}\over{(n+2)(n)!}}={{2n+2}\over{n+2}}=>{{2n+2-n+n}\over{n+2}} = {{2n+2}\over{2n+2}}+{{n}\over{n+2}}=1+{{2}\over{n+2}}\ge1$$
${{a_{n+1}}\over{a_n}}\ge1 \Rightarrow {a_{n+1}}\ge{a_n}$ then the sequence is monotone increasing.

ii) BOUNDED:
$$\left|{{2^n}\over{(n+1)!}}\right|={2^n}.{1\over{(n+1)!}}\le1$$
Then the sequence is bounded.

iii) Is monotone and bounded, so the sequence is convergent.

There is an error here?

Comment: The bounded argument is missing the power of the 2... and what do you mean by the straigts brackets?

Comment: The absolute value of that expression. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in: 
$$\frac{2(n+1)!}{(n+2)!} = \frac{(2n+2)n!}{(n+2)n!}$$
Instead it is:
$$\frac{2(n+1)!}{(n+2)!} = \frac{(2n+2)n!}{(n+2)(n+1)n!} = \frac{2}{n+2} < 1$$
This means that $a_{n+1} <a_{n}$ so the sequence is strictly decreasing and $a_{n} > 0$.

Comment: Why I can't do it?

Comment: Because your a missing the (n+1) from the (n+2)! and you cant just vanish a part of the product. $(n+2)!=(n+2)(n+1)(n)(n-1)..2*1=(n+2)(n+1)(n!)$.

Comment: So, if I have: (n+5)n! I can separate this (n+5)(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)n! or simply (n+5)(n+4)! ?

Comment: Yes, only not (n+5)n!, but (n+5)!. Go and read a few examples of the factorial function to get some better idea why that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you have any actual $argument$ for boundedness, unless you are allowed to assume the factorial function grows faster than the exponential which would be very surprising in the context of this problem... you just took the $2^n$ off of the fraction and asserted that it was bounded.

You can do it inductively: $2^0=1!$ and $2^1=2!$ so the assertion is true in those cases. If $2 \leq k+1$ and $2^{k-1}\leq k!$ then $2^k\leq (k+1)!$. These premises are obviously true, therefore boundedness.